# How to generate a URL with a sub domain to a new URL with a query string?

Tags: nginx

I'm very new to [nginx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx), and now I want to use nginx to generate a new URL from the URL the user passed.

Example:

The user types into the browser like **http://us.domain.com**, and I want nginx to generate **http://www.domain.com/?portal=us** or **http://domain.com/?portal=us**.

How can I use rewrite in nginx to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Something not as fast, but more general:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  domain.com;
    if ($host ~* (.*)\.domain\.com ) {
       set $subdomain $1;
       rewrite (.*) http://domain.com/?portal=$subdomain;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean redirect, right?

```
http {
  # ...
  server {
    server_name us.domain.com;
    location / {
      rewrite ^/ http://www.domain.com/?portal=us;
    }
  }
}
```